# I’ve created a bootable Windows 10 USB Drive, but my desktop will not load it

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb, bios

I followed a [tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/) online to create a bootable Windows 10 USB drive on Linux, but it does not boot when I choose it from the boot menu. I’ve been waiting for a while, hoping it just had to load, but it’s been almost 20 minutes, and basically nothing is happening, other than a black screen with a cursor in the top left. I am using a desktop pc, and the BIOS is “MSI CLICK BIOS 5” (not sure if that matters). Also, would it change anything if it’s plugged into a USB 3.0 instead of a USB 2.0 slot? It is in exFAT format.

EDIT: I eventually gave up on that, so now I'm trying to reformat the device in GPT FAT32 for UEFI booting instead of Legacy.

EDIT 2: I’ve solved the problem, so I am no longer in need of answers.

Comment: You are trying to boot into Windows 10 or WinPE?  The article is for WinPE.  Hopefully, you understand that and are not expecting to boot into Windows itself.

Comment: Is your Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) set to boot in Legacy MBR Mode or UEFI Mode? UEFI will most likely  not understand exFAT partition. UEFI & Legacy booting are different and requires that USB drive is created in different ways. For UEFI Boot you can extract the ISO on FAT32. Again, there are ways to tackle if install.wim > 4GB. For legacy boot MBR needs to be correctly created additionally.

Comment: You cannot install Windows from a exFAT partition to my knowledge.  If that’s what you used that’s one reason it’s not working.

Comment: @patkim How do I check what mode the Firmware is booting from? And how do I paste install.wim if the partition is not in exFAT? Is there another format I can use that _does_ allow > 4 GB files?

Comment: @MatthewNorman Re: boot mode. If you go to https://us.msi.com/support/technical_details/MB_BIOS_Manual and look for the first image with the time at 13:23 you will see where to check the BIOS mode. (You want to install Windows 10 with it set to UEFI unless you have some specific reason not to.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not discovered exactly what I was doing wrong, but I have solved the problem by putting the Windows files on a new partition on my SSD, making them load both faster and more efficiently. Windows now boots successfully.

Comment: Anyone know how to close a question so that it doesn’t say that it still needs answers?